# Update in SQL based on data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a question regarding the UPDATE operation in (My)SQL.

Assume we have two tables with both 3 columns:

- village (villagename, riverdepth, countrycode)
- country (countrycode, countryname, population)

I want to update all columns 'riverdepth' from the table 'village' (but only the villages in italy). The countrycode has to be retrieved from the table 'country', because we do not know the countrycode of italy yet.

*Assuming that the total reduction of the riverdepths in the whole country 'italy' last year was 10.000 litres, and all villages have lost the same amount of the riverdepth.*

This is what i came up with so far:

```
UPDATE village
SET riverdepth = riverdepth - (10000 / COUNT(villagename))
WHERE countrycode(
SELECT countrycode
FROM country
WHERE countryname = 'italy')
```

Although this returns the error 'invalid use of group function'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have an implicit aggregation because of the `count()`.  This is not allowed in an `update`.  Instead, one method is to pre-aggregate the data and use a `join`:

```
UPDATE village v JOIN
       (SELECT v.countrycode, count(v.villagename) as cnt
        FROM village v
        GROUP BY v.countrycode
       ) vv
       ON v.countrycode = vv.countrycode
    SET v.riverdepth = v.riverdepth - (10000 / vv.cnt)
    WHERE v.countrycode IN (SELECT c2.countrycode
                            FROM country c2
                            WHERE c2.countryname = 'italy'
                           );
```

Your `WHERE` clause is also missing an `IN`.

Comment: Thank you, with some modifications it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use UPDATE JOIN:

```
UPDATE village JOIN country USING(countrycode)
SET riverdepth = riverdepth - (10000 / COUNT(villagename))
WHERE countryname = 'italy'
```